# Chrome, Safari hangs while reading from localStorage while Firefox is good?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I have the following code which fires off when `Queue` is clicked

```
$('#queue').click(function(){
        $("#feature").load("templates/queue.html", function(){
            var template = $('queue_item').clone();
            if (localStorage['queue'] == null) {
                $('.queue_list').append('<p>You have not added any video to the queue yet</p>');
            } else {
                var queue_list = JSON.parse(localStorage['queue']);
                for (var i = 0; i < queue_list.length; i++) {
                    console.log(queue_list[i]);
                    var item = fill_queue_item(queue_list[i]);
                    $('.queue_list').append(item).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

- Depending on number of `items` user added to queue this code creates a node and insert into `queue_list`
- When I test this on Firfox, things are pretty fine, but Safari and Chrome almost die to perform the same operation

**Question**
- How can I make Chrome and Safari happy like Firefox and let them do things fast?

**UPDATE**

```
function fill_queue_item(data) {
    var template = $('.queue_item').clone();
    template.removeClass('hide-item');
    template.find('img').attr('src', data.thumbnail);
    template.find('.title').html(data.title);
    template.attr('id', data.url);
    template.addClass('view-item');
    return template;
}
```

The `queue` can contain any number of items, but for Chrome/Safari it is not more than 20

Comment: How many items are there in the queue?  What does `fill_queue_item()` do and where is it's code?

Comment: @jfriend00, added with code and number of items, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing:

```
var template = $('.queue_item').clone();
```

to this:

```
var template = $('.queue_item').first().clone();
```

The way you have it now, you are cloning every single `.queue_item` so as you add more and more, you are creating a lot of unnecessary clones when you really only mean to create one new clone each time to use as a template.  If you did this 20 times on the previous results each time, you could end up with `2^20` cloned elements which would be over a million objects.

Comment: great catch @jfreind00, this speeded up the loading drastically, my bad, I am very new to `jQuery` and trying to learn things here, thank you for your help

Comment: @daydreamer - not you also have a `var template = $('queue_item').clone();` in the main click handler that is not used.  You should remove that.

Comment: yes, I am going to do the cleanup in a while, thanks for noticing that out! :)